# Call to a member function getList() on a non-object

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH'))
    exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Builder extends CI_Controller {

    private $uri_segment = 4;
    private $per_page = 4;
    private $num_links = 6;
    private $model;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // Your own constructor code
        $this->load->library('parser');
        $this->load->model($this->model);
        //$this->model = $this->User;
    }

    public function get_start_row(){
        return $this->uri->segment($this->uri_segment, 0);
    }

    public function get_total_row(){
        return $this->model->count();
    }

    public function pagination($data){
        $this->load->library('pagination');
            $config['base_url'] = $data['url'];
            $config['total_rows'] = $data['total_row'];
            $config['per_page'] = $this->per_page;
            $config['num_links'] = $this->num_links;
            $config['uri_segment'] = $this->uri_segment;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div class="text-center"><ul class="pagination">';
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        return $this->pagination->create_links();
    }

    public function index() { 
            //$this->session->unset_userdata('_task');
            //$this->session->unset_userdata('_value');  

            $start = $this->get_start_row();
            $data['result_list'] = $this->model->get_list(array(), $start, $this->per_page);

            $display_row = '';
            if(empty($data['result_list'])){

                $data['result_list'] = array(
                                            array('user_id' => '','user_name' => '','user_tel' => '','user_email' => '',
                                            'user_username' => '','user_password' => '','user_permission' => '')
                                            );

                    $display_row = 'display:none';

            }

            $data['txt_search'] = '';
            $data['pagination'] = '';                           
            $data['display_list'] = $display_row;
            $this->parser->parse('builder/user', $data);
        }

    public function save() {
        $post = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE); // returns all POST/GET items with XSS filter 
        $data = array(
            'user_id' => $post['user_id(Primary)'], 
            'user_name' => $post['user_name'], 
            'user_tel' => $post['user_tel'], 
            'user_email' => $post['user_email'], 
            'user_username' => $post['user_username'], 
            'user_password' => $post['user_password'], 
            'user_permission' => $post['user_permission'] 
        );
            $this->model->id = $post['id'];
            if($this->model->save($data)){
            $result = array('result' => true);
        }else{
            $result = array(
                'result' => false,
                'message' => $this->db->error()
            );
        }
            echo json_encode($result);
    }

    public function delete() {
        $this->user->id = $this->input->post('id', true);
            if($this->user->save($data)){
            $result = array('result' => true);
        }else{
            $result = array(
                'result' => false,
                'message' => $this->db->error()
            );
        }
            echo json_encode($result);
    }

}

?>
```

> **A PHP Error was encountered**
>  Severity: Error Message: Call to a member
>   function get_list() on a non-object
>  Filename: controllers/Builder.php
>   Line Number: 46 Backtrace:

Comment: `private $model` is empty no model load .... give name of your model file where get_list() method exist

Comment: Which on is line 46 ? The Golden Rule for Questions: **"Imagine You’re Trying To Answer The Question"**

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the constructor where you call `$this->load->model($this->model);` When that is called the class property `$model` has no value. So you have essentially called `$this->load->model(NULL);` which is meaningless and so there will not be an object called `model' in scope.

You probably want to do something more like `$this->load->model('user_model');` or, if you insist on using the class property you have to set it first.

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('parser');
    $this->model = 'user_model';
    $this->load->model($this->model);
}
```

Or perhaps I have misunderstood your intent. If so, please let us know you goal.